# App crashed While integration of My framework to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I got following error while integrating Framework to My Project

> dyld:  Library not loaded: @rpath/HelperFrameWork.framework/HelperFrameWork
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/searchnative-ios1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ADD59725-025E-4016-934C-B3584877176F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3836A80A-1260-49E8-A08F-373A19CC4A76/TestApplication.app/TestApplication
>   Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     /Users/searchnative-ios1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ADD59725-025E-4016-934C-B3584877176F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3836A80A-1260-49E8-A08F-373A19CC4A76/TestApplication.app/Frameworks/HelperFrameWork.framework/HelperFrameWork:
>   required code signature missing for
>   '/Users/searchnative-ios1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ADD59725-025E-4016-934C-B3584877176F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/3836A80A-1260-49E8-A08F-373A19CC4A76/TestApplication.app/Frameworks/HelperFrameWork.framework/HelperFrameWork'

I have also added to  embedded Binaries and Linked Framework and Libraries:

[image]

If change framework status to Optional instead of Required under the General Tab of target.  then i got following error .

> dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol
>   __TMaC15HelperFrameWork12UtilityClass in /Users/searchnative-ios1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ADD59725-025E-4016-934C-B3584877176F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/236D6027-1420-4BEC-9383-47C5853E3011/TestApplication.app/TestApplication
>   because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded dyld: can't resolve
>   symbol __TMaC15HelperFrameWork12UtilityClass in
>   /Users/searchnative-ios1/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/ADD59725-025E-4016-934C-B3584877176F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/236D6027-1420-4BEC-9383-47C5853E3011/TestApplication.app/TestApplication
>   because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded

Any one can help me to how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do you have separate project for HelperFrameWork?

Comment: yes i have separate project.

Comment: You have problem with signature. Usually you don't sign frameworks so without project settings it is hard to say what is wrong.

Comment: then i need to sign framework with valid provisional profile ?

Comment: No, usually you don't need to sign framework.

Comment: Then what i do for solve this errors ?